# use jstl tag inside spring's select tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

by default, I want to select a few data in the dropdown which is already in the database.but when I use JSTL tags such as (if, when and conditional tags) inside spring tag I am getting below error.

`<form:option value="${emp.key}" selected="selected" >${emp.value}</form:option>` which works for me. but i want is

```
         <form:option value="${emp.key}" <c:choose><c:when test = "${fn:contains(cc_HeadUid, emp.key)}"> selected="selected" </c:when></c:choose> >${emp.value}</form:option>  //ccHeadUid is String[] .


     i tried this also.   <form:option value="${emp.key}" ${'foo'.equals('foo') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''} >${emp.value}</form:option>
```

already i have included all the header tags.

i am getting following error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/costcenter/cc_edit.jsp (line: [56], column: [45]) Unterminated [&lt;form:option] tag
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1006)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1683)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1683)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1683)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java
```

Comment: Did you get the exception at second attempt @ this (${'foo'.equals('foo') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''} ) too?. And selected='true' not selected. Compare string using "==" not equals.

Comment: i have tried both selected="selected" and selected='true' but same error

Comment: selected is not defined attribute in spring tld on form:option. My bad first glance i thought it's JSP. So chhnge your code to for each items and then form: options to option then add condition.